# File opening for reading in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am developing a project in Visual Studio 2012 and I can not figure out why this code always return with "The file can not be opened!", because tram.exe and stops.txt is in the same (Debug) folder.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main (int count, char *arguments[]) {
    if (count > 1) {
        ifstream input("stops.txt");

        if (input.is_open()) {

        } else {
            cout << "The file can not be opened!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When You navigate to the directory in shell and execute this file inside shell, does it work there?
If so, You should a ) provide absolute path or b ) inspect the Environmentvariables of VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio, by default, will set your Working Directory to `$(ProjectDir)` - that is, the folder where your vcxproj lives - this won't be the same as the folder your exe gets written out to, so you won't find your text file in the current directory.

Either manually change the working directory <kbd>Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging</kbd> to match the target path, or change your filename to point to the full (or relative) path.

Comment: I changed the working directory to "..\Debug", but still do not work.

Comment: You can't set the relative directory like that - you'll need to either enter a full directory, or use one of the macros (if you pick the <Edit...> option it'll show you all the macros and what they expand to.   In this case $(TargetDir) should do what you want

Comment: With $(TargetDir) set, the situation is still same. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Find out what the current working directory of your running process is with

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx

Example:

```
unsigned int length = 0;
char* workingDirectory;

length = GetCurrentDirectory(0, NULL); // How large should my buffer be?
workingDirectory = new char[length]; // Allocate buffer
GetCurrentDirectory( (DWORD) length, (LPTSTR) workingDirectory); // Fill with string
std::cout << workingDirectory << std::endl; // Output string
delete [] workingDirectory; // Make sure to delete it
```

You can put this into a function

```
void getWorkingDirectory(std::string& dir)
{
    unsigned int length = 0;
    char* buffer;
    length = GetCurrentDirectory(0, NULL);
    buffer = new char[length];
    GetCurrentDirectory( (DWORD) length, (LPTSTR) buffer);
    dir = buffer;
    delete [] buffer;
}
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this.

Answer (score -2):

Use the below line of code:

**ifstream input("stops.txt", std::fstream::out);**

Its working.

Comment: That would open his input file for writing, which isn't the error - it's failing because it can't find the file

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: With the specified scenario, when i put this statement in the code, I could see that file is opened. With the statement "fstream input("stops.txt");", i could see that the file is not opened.